# lists adding elements (and splitting)

Tags: list

I'm adding a list and when I use `MyArray|MyElement` I print to screen and I get:

> [obj1,obj2] | obj3

which isn't correct, is it? Ideally I want it to be:

> [Obj1,Obj2,Obj3]

if I use `MyArray|[MyElement]`printing out gives me:

> [Obj1,Obj2] | [Obj3]

is this the equivalent to [Obj1,Obj2,Obj3] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the syntax `[ MyElement | MyArray ]`, you'd get

```
[Obj3, Obj1, Obj2]
```

This is what's known as "consing" an element onto a list. You could also use an `append/3` predicate, like this:

```
append( MyArray, [MyElement], X).
```

which produces

```
X = [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, its because I was appending to the end of the list and the tail is always an array....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you question, but I'll try to help.

Try this if it works for you:

```
add2end(X,[],[X]).
add2end(X,[H|T],[H|NewT]):-add2end(X,T,NewT).
```

And for splitting:

split(L,N,L1,L2) :- the list L1 contains the first N elements
 of the list L, the list L2 contains the remaining elements.
(list,integer,list,list) (?,+,?,?)

```
split(L,0,[],L).
split([X|Xs],N,[X|Ys],Zs) :- N > 0, N1 is N - 1, split(Xs,N1,Ys,Zs).
```